# Question counts are wrong when not on the "newest" tab

Tags: feature-request, tags, question-count

On tag pages (`/questions/tagged/foo`) the question count on the right (`N questions tagged`[foo](/questions/tagged/foo)) is only accurate for the newest/votes/active tabs.  On other tabs, the count is actually for only that tab, but the text still just says "questions tagged" as opposed to "featured questions tagged" or "frequently asked questions tagged" &c.

This is especially confusing if you were browsing featured questions before visiting the tag page.  Frequently in that case none of the tabs are selected (because there are no questions with bounties for that tag), suggesting that no filtering is happening, while just the opposite is true.

Comment: Post the separate retag request as a separate question.

Comment: @MatthewRead Yeah, I considered that, but since all synomizing happens via meta instead of the [purported system](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms), I didn't feel like the ad-hoc system had much claim to correct process.