# Can't find questions with a specific tag, but I can see there's a question with such a tag

Tags: bug

There's [at least one question with the cfg tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586775/control-flow-graph-of-a-program), but if I click on the [cfg](/questions/tagged/cfg) tag, no questions are listed.

What's going on? How then do I find questions with the cfg tag?

**Update:**
Apparently, clicking on "Newest" will show questions with such a tag. Thanks for helping, everyone!

Comment: No repro, I can see 43 questions tagged [tag:cfg].

Comment: You've obviously checked that the [tag:cfg] tag is not one of your ignored tags, right?

Comment: A screenshot might shed some light on this.

Answer (score 3):

If you were previously on a tab that isn't part of the 'questions tagged' view, e.g., 'featured', you will still be on that tab when you go into the 'questions tagged' view.

At a glance, this can make it appear that there are no questions in that tag, because [the question number isn't tab-sensitive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120061/137004).

The solution is to select one of the tabs that's present on that view.

Answer (score 0):

Check the question type before selecting the question. If you have selected "Unanswered Questions" and then selecting tag `cfg`, it will never show you questions which have one or more answers. Similar for featured question also.