# Searching for multiple tags only returns some of the matching questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search, tag-search

Here's a search for two tags, `meteor` and `routing`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routing+meteor

It only returns [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461097/meteorjs-routing-with-backbone-js):

[image: only one question returned]

But there's another one, tagged with those two tags, which the search doesn't find:

- [How do I create dynamic URL's with Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656001/how-do-i-create-dynamic-urls-with-meteor)

If I'm logged out, the search does return both questions.

I'm not ignoring any tags:

[image]

Comment: Shows them both for me...

Comment: Are you ignoring one of the tags on the missing question?

Comment: Not ignoring any tags... edited the question with more screenshots. IF I'm logged out, I do see both results.

Comment: Related: [Question counts are wrong when not on the "newest" tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120061) :P

Comment: @TimStone That's the answer. Mind posting it as one? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the FAQ tab, which only shows that one specific question. Switch to "newest" (or "votes", or "active") to get both results.

Keep in mind that the your selected tab is persisted, since this can impact what you see on future searches.

Comment: Ah... ok. I haven't noticed that tab at all. It blends too much in the background. Feel free to raise this as a UX issue if you like.